# Prove that $H$ is a subvector space of $K^{n\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\ge 1$ and $K\in\{R,C\}$. $H$ is the set of all $n\times n$ matrices over $K$ whose row and column sums are equal. Prove that $H$ is a subvector space of $K^{n\times n}$ with $\mathrm{dim} H=n^2-2n+2$ and determine the Basis of $H$.

I know that for something to be a subvector space it has to be closed under addition, multiplication and be non-empty. How do I use this to solve the above ?